# Bar chart Dynamic Update with unequal number of bars

Tags: javascript, charts, morris.js

I am trying to implement Morris.js Bar chart:

http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/258/embed?js,output

I want to update the chart dynamically and every time the number of columns in one data is different.

Some thing like this:

in year 2006: Series A, Series B

in year 2007: Series A, Series B, Series C

in year 2006 Series C should not be displayed.